Show '1' (10^0) on a ggplot2 histogram having a log10-transformed y axis
I am trying to plot a histogram using ggplot2, in which the counts can span a very large range. So, I decided to try to transform the y axis to log10 scale. This is working well, except for values of 1. I'd like them to be visible on my plot but did not find a way to do so.
I've tried to create a minimal example to explain what I mean.
# Create an example data frame with observations `obs` and values ranging 1-10
# 1 to 5 occur twice, while 6 to 10 only once
example_df <- data.frame(obs=letters[1:15], value=c(1:10, 1:5))

We can then create a simple histogram, e.g.
ggplot(example_df, aes(x=value)) + geom_histogram()

Which results in what you'd expect.
However, if I transform the y-axis (scale_y_log10()), then all 1 disappear. I get a warning that 'log-10 transformation introduced infinite values', but I don't have any null values (log10(0) giving such error would make sense but here the minimum is 1?). I tried using scale_y_log10(na.value=1), but that does not fix the issue.
Any pointers on new things I may try?

You might try scale_y_continuous(trans = scales::pseudo_log_trans())?

First, judging by your data set, I don't think you actually want to make a histogram, you want to make a bar plot. They look similar, but a bar plot plots counts of categorical variable, and a histogram plots counts of a continuous variable, after first dividing the range up into bins.
R (ggplot2) has two ways of making bar plots, geom_bar, for when you want R to do the counting, and geom_col, for when you've already done the counting. So I think you want this:
ggplot(example_df, aes(x=obs, y=value)) + geom_col()
Putting the y-axis on the log scale then works...
ggplot(example_df, aes(x=obs, y=value)) + geom_col() + scale_y_log10()
but is generally considered to be misleading and a bad idea.
Visually, the length of the bar should correspond to how much "stuff" there is; if the bar is twice as long, then the counts should be twice as high. But that's not how log-scale works; instead a certain distance corresponds to twice as much, no matter where it is on the scale (ie, it converts multiplicative relationships to additive relationships).
Another way people say this is that a bar chart should always include zero on the vertical axis -- but on the log scale, there is no zero! (There is 10^0, but that's equal to 1.) So there's no good place to start the bars.
The first thing to try is to instead simply plot points instead of bars with geom_point.

Excellent advice, over and above answering OP#s original question.

As Jon suggested, try a pseudo_log transform:
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)
library(patchwork)

example_df <- data.frame(
  value = c(rep(7, 50), sample(1:100, 50, replace =TRUE))
            )
example_df

p1 <- ggplot(example_df, aes(x=value)) + 
  geom_histogram()

p2 <- ggplot(example_df, aes(x=value)) + 
  geom_histogram()+
  scale_y_continuous(trans = scales::pseudo_log_trans())

p1 + p2


